# Why is the separation of Kosovo from Serbia treated differently from the breakup of other Yugoslav nations from Belgrade?

Tags: international-relations, secession, kosovo, yugoslavia

When Yugoslavia began to split up, it didn't take more than a couple of years for the international community to recognize the splinter states as sovereign nations. If I understand correctly, this recognition came before Serbia officially conceded to have lost its former territories. However when Kosovo attempted a similar move and decided to become independent from Belgrade, this was treated as an act of unilateral secession by [a significant number of countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Kosovo) and Kosovo is still in limbo [26 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Kosova) later.

What's the reasoning behind this? Why didn't at least some countries support Belgrade's right to control Croatian or Slovenian territory?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do with the different status of Kosovo - Croatia etc. where republics within a socialist federation, whereas Kosovo is a province of Serbia (or so Serbia says).  I have to admit that I don't know enough details to make  a good answer.

Comment: Partly because the state it was part of continues to claim the territory. This is not the case in the other examples mentioned.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons if I understand correctly, most countries recognized the split off Republics before Belgrade officially did

Comment: Kosovo declared independence just under 11 years ago.  Where do you get "20" from?

Comment: @phoog - that is correct. If the [first declaration of independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Kosova) is taken into account, we have more than 20 years.

Comment: Related: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64589/how-and-why-did-e-g-chechnya-differ-in-status-from-entities-like-armenia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two competing principles in international law.

1. Nations have a right of [self-determination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilsonianism).
2. Nations have a right of [territorial integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_integrity).

The obvious problem comes up when part of a nation declares itself a nation and wants to secede. If they are a People with a capital P within a multi-nation state, then self-determination may win. If they are just a faction or a province within a state, then territorial integrity may win. How it comes out depends on the political climate at the time, and of course also on the self-interest of various political actors.

- Croatia and Slovenia were Socialist Republics within Yugoslavia.
- One could argue that Croatia and Slovenia had a stronger national tradition than Kosovo. At least it was perceived that way in the West, and the Warsaw Pact was disintegrating.
- The timing allowed Croatian and Slovenian public relations teams to put their quest for independence into the same narrative as the breakup of the Warsaw Pact, which was *viewed* in the West as a liberation of oppressed Peoples from the Communist yoke. (Viewers in Russia have a different view, of course.)
- By contrast, Kosovo was an autonomous province within the Socialist Republic of Serbia.
- By the time it fought for independence, the West was fed up with fighting in the Balkans and Russia was asserting a role on the global stage, including support for Serbia.
- And as user24240 put it bluntly in his answer, it was possible to paint the KLA as a terrorist group. The label *terrorist* is becoming almost as arbitrary as *democrat* was during the Cold War, but it cost them support.

Some people in the West really didn't like that the KLA forced their hand and got them into a war with Serbia. That reduced goodwill towards the Kosovo. I think the effects are still lingering.